# Requisição em tempo real com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Preciso atualizar algumas informações em tempo real, fiz algumas pesquisa aqui no stackoverflow e encontrei uma postagem muito boa, mas não consegui fazer funcionar.
Na postagem foi explicado o seguinte:

Ajax que notifica caso haja uma alteração ou não, caso seja detectado a alteração só assim então fazer a requisição para atualizar o novo conteúdo:

**1ª Opção:**

```
var auto_atualiza = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('possui_alteracao.php', function(data) {
    if (data.possui) {
      $('#meudiv').load('listadados.php');
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```

**2ª Opção:**

```
var cachedDOM = $('#meudiv').html();
var auto_atualiza = setInterval(function () {
  $.get('listadados.php', function(data) {
    if(data != cachedDOM) {
      $('#meudiv').html(data);
      cachedDOM = $('#meudiv').html();
    }
  });
}, 30000);
```

**Dúvidas**

O script está correto?
Como fica o código em php para as opções 1 e 2?

Agradeço.

Comment: O que você já testou no PHP? Não tem nada de mais no código que vc copiou, se o script responder ele vai aceitar.

Comment: A solução que você está propondo pode ser eficiente, porém uma dica é que ao invés de usar o setInterval é usar socket para que quando houver mudanças no servidor já seja atualizado no front. Existem várias discussões sobre esse assunto no SOen.

Comment: Perfeito, irei trocar pelo socket. Uma outra dúvida é de como vai ficar o código php para que funcione. Por exemplo: $pesquisa_sql_menu   = "SELECT * FROM venda";
$select_menu = $pdo->prepare($pesquisa_sql_menu);
$executa_menu = $select_menu->execute();

while($reg_menu = $select_menu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

echo $reg_menu->ap_qnt_bks;

}